# Given that I can get the hls url of this twitch stream, how do I buffer exactly 5 minutes of "source" quality vs 5 minutes of "medium" quality in c#?

Tags: c#, twitch

Here is the command using live streamer to get the url

```
livestreamer http://twitch.tv/riotgames source -j --player-continuous-http

{
  "headers": {
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, compress",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.7.3 Windows/7"
  },
  "type": "hls",
  "url": "http://video15.dfw01.hls.ttvnw.net/hls57/riotgames_15358062512_2731352
84/chunked/py-index-live.m3u8?token=id=7959476983820996588,bid=15358062512,exp=1
437309846,node=video15-1.dfw01.hls.justin.tv,nname=video15.dfw01,fmt=chunked&sig
=b1232b4cf2261775aab78617d66b383713dd1a2e"
}
```

I want to make a program that someone can say, hey clip the last 5 minutes of my stream, I wasn't able to because I was making plays.